# missing a command building android kernel

Tags: android, perl, build, kernel

I have been trying to build an android kernel for a certain device, the Huawei Vitria, they finally uploaded their kernel source about 2 months ago so I try to build it the normal way which fails so I fix the main errors I see and get the kernel to build finally but, then I notice one error while building. I look into this file and see that they are using a weird way of building I think instead of the normal defconfigs, using a generic defconfig then a configuration file to configure their devices ontop of that(they've done this before but not to this extent), which leads me to think I'm missing a command to select the device config ontop of the defconfig to set up the drivers, but don't know what command was used.

So might there be a way to find out the command by looking at these two files

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KainXS/android_kernel_huawei_y301a2/jellybean/drivers/huawei/hsad/parse_product.pl

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KainXS/android_kernel_huawei_y301a2/jellybean/drivers/huawei/hsad/parse_product_id.pl

thanks

Comment: Whoever ignorantly close voted this, **building** and *modifying* a kernel is not a "Question about general computing hardware or software"  Additionally, it is unlikely that someone would attempt this (vs re-using the existing build), except as a precursor to doing *development* on the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how much help this is, but the first command seems to want to be called with a parameter of a path to an XML file.

```
./parse_product.pl /ab/cd/hw_xxy_configs.xml
PRODUCT: xxy
reads: '/ab/cd/hw_xxy_configs.xml'
```

It pulls out some data from that file and pastes it into a `.c` file which presumably goes into the build configuration.

So, you're looking for an XML file containing your product-name.

The second file calls the first repeatedly to generate a set of .c files. Now - this second script takes an XML file as an argument, but I'm afraid I can't tell what it might be called. The file looks like it should contain product names and board-ids if that is any help.

Comment: thanks, that really helps thanks, now I just need to find the xml(if they included it).